# Display query string SEOmatic

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I'm using the [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) plugin and would like the query string in my URL to display with the site's title. Is this possible to add with the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

So you can definitely do this via [Dynamic Twig Meta](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/10.-Dynamic-Twig-SEO-Meta)